# XOR in domino logic

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates

I was reading about domino logic and I noticed that several resources mention that domino logic can't be used for inverting functions like (NAND, NOR) and also can't be used for XOR.

I understand why we can't implement inverting functions, but why not XOR?

Can't we use a PDN that's similar to the PDN of an AOI22 and utilize inputs in their inverted and non inverted forms (A A_bar, B B_bar) ?

Answer (score 1):

The statement  *" .. domino logic can't be used for inverting functions like (NAND, NOR) and also can't be used for XOR.. "* is not valid if you have inverted form of inputs.

If you have `A_bar` and `B_bar`, then `OR` between them will give you `NAND` and `AND` between them will give you `NOR`. In that case, you can implement `XOR` also.